# Opening the Add/Remove Programs dialog takes too much time

Tags: windows, windows-xp, addremoveprograms

I'm on a WinXP Pro SP3 box. Some time ago, I noticed that opening the Add/Remove programs window takes a lot of time. The window itself opens, but it's building the list that takes so long. I fired FileMon from SysInternals, and it turned out that the process that's supposed to list the programs tries to open every file on my HD.

Anybody experienced this? Any cure?

Thanks
ulu

Comment: NP Related. Voted to close. But you can try out Revo Unistaller. I have the same problem sometimes but Revo is much better. Search for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a programming question, but the answer is sorta cool (and a good heads-up for those writing installers):

[It's scanning because some programs don't provide enough information when they're installed.](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2004/07/09/178342.aspx)